# Ubuntu package for alloy analyzer?

Tags: package-management

So I'm experimenting with Ubuntu 12.04 after using ArchLinux for the last 2 years or so.  I'm looking for an Ubuntu package for [Alloy Analyzer](http://alloy.mit.edu/alloy/index.html) and can't seem to find one.

I've a hard time believing that the Arch package repositories are more complete than the Ubuntu repositories are so I assume I'm just being a dummy.  I can't find it through the software center or `apt-cache search` though.  Any suggestions?  I believe the Arch package may be in the AUR, does Ubuntu have an equivalent?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I believe the Arch package may be in the AUR, does Ubuntu have an equivalent?

The equivalent for Arch User Repositories" in Ubuntu are called **PPAs** (personal package archives). See https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas for more information.

That said, I didn't find any PPAs containing Alloy Analyzer. Perhaps the reason why is because all "installing" it require is downloading and running a JAR file?

The only update/check you may require is a simple `wget` to check for and download a newer version:

`wget -N http://alloy.mit.edu/alloy/downloads/alloy4.jar`

every once in a while. Or make it a cron job if you wish :)

Comment: Ah, thanks for the info about PPAs I wasn't aware of them. :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is a stupid suggestion, but did you try downloading the [jar file](http://alloy.mit.edu/alloy/download.html) and running it?

Comment: Well, I can do that as a last resort. I want it in the package manager though so I don't have to track updates etc.